# Asp.net mvc sub-controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to create a site structure like this
/demo/
/demo/admin/create
/demo/admin/edit/id

I can create a DemoController which will contains admin. But how to show create/edit pages? The create/edit pages can be accessible only after user is logged in. Where to put create/edit pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are certain that you should implement strictly that URL strusture, then maybe "areas" solution would fit you (though not sure, just had a brief view). But I think, that for a small project you could simply make:

- separate "admin" controller (that would lead to /demo, /admin/create, /admin/edit/id);
- or you could possibly use custom [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx);

As for the authorization, you should look into [ASP.NET Web Application Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/330a99hc.aspx) and [User authentication and authorisation in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524086/user-authentication-and-authorisation-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is create a route for /demo/admin, then assign that route to a new controller called DemoAdminController.  To make this only accessible to logged in users, you use the Windows Forms authentication system.  A sample is provided with the default application generated by MVC.

Answer (score 1):

i agree an area should do the trick or you can add a custom route that points the the controller  if you want to lock down the whole section as an admin only section i think areas would be the way to go on this one

Answer (score 1):

Pretty old question, Google landed me here right now.

There is also another way to reach the goal: the `Route` and `RoutePrefix` attribute.

Just a small chunk of code for reference.

```
[RoutePrefix("demo")]
public class DemoController : Controller
{
  [Route("")]
  public ActionResult Index()  { } // default route: /demo

  [Route("admin/create")]
  public ActionResult Create() { } // /demo/admin/create

  [Route("admin/edit/{id}")]
  public ActionResult Edit(int id) { } // /demo/admin/edit/5
}
```

For this to work, the attribute routing must be enabled. In most case is enough to add:

```
 routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

in RouteConfig.cs.

Example:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to use Areas. See docs here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx