# User Login in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I am just a beginner of ASP.NET MVC. I have done some page by asp.net mvc but now I need to do form log in by using MVC. The login user name and password are store in database. Can anyone propose or share me some idea of how to do that? I really have no idea about that. Thanks.

Comment: if possible you can google it for examples i think u can find many of them.

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/256237 is the link that can help u.

Comment: @KaranShah : I search in google ready. But the solution is not fix with what I need :).

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs try this out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are new to Asp.net MVC, I would suggest you to follow a tutorial which will provide a great insight of how things shape up in this new framework. You can follow the Tutorial [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1) from asp.net

It contains all the basic ingredients of a web application from user authentication to CRUD operations.

Comment: As I read it, the account information of that not store in database, right?

Comment: They are stored in the database only. But it uses the default membership provided by .NET

Comment: Can I change the aspnet_User and some other table to my own table in database?

Comment: no you can't. For that you will have to implement your own custom provider. To learn more about this, read : [Implementing a Membership Provide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) and [How to: Implement a Custom Membership User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730.aspx)

Comment: So I really cannot modify the default membership provider that provide by asp.net MVC? I think if create new, it is very complicated for me.

Comment: It's not that hard as it looks in the beginning though its bit trivial. But basically all you need to do is inherit from [ MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) abstract class and implement the required members. The required members list is available on above links.

Comment: You might also take a look at this [article](http://syntaxwarriors.com/2011/mvc3-custom-membership-provider/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5301/discussion-between-socheata-and-pankaj-upadhyay)

Comment: @ Pankaj Upadhyay : But that article is not connect to database.

Comment: Mate, I hope this answer provides your a great insight as to how things are needed to be done : [Custom membership with db](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2780406/570928)

Answer (score 3):

You may configure your web-app via Form Authentication. Take a look at tutorial - Authenticating Users with [Forms Authentication.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs) and SO thread - [User authentication and authorisation in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524086/user-authentication-and-authorisation-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I have table Customer, and it store ID, username and password of user. I want to query it and take it to verify with the user name and password that the user fill in the form of view. I don't want to use membership provider of ASP.NET. So can you tell me, how can I do beside that? Thanks.

Comment: @socheata - Please read this post and then decide which auth system you want to use. http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/09/09/38390/

Comment: Can I change the aspnet_User and some other table to my own table in database?