# Simple Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I am wondering what is the simplest and fastest way I can do authentication in asp.net mvc?

I currently am making a site and want to launch it soon. The site is more like a test run and see if the idea will stick. I don't want to spend time working on an an elaborate authentication such as using openId/openAuth for my admin section just yet.

In the future I see users will need to log in as well and this is when I would implement something more to the admin section as well.

Right now I just want something that can stop anyone but me from getting to that area. If possible I rather not even have a html form with a username or password to type in the credentials.

I was looking at the security box but not sure if I can use this or if this some forms authentication or what.

[image]

Comment: This link may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524086/user-authentication-and-authorisation-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest, if you want support for multiple users right now, is the [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx)

First step is use the [aspnet_regsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx) command to generate membership tables in your database:

> aspnet_regsql -S localhost -d "your_database_name" -A all -U sql_username -P sql_password

From there, it's just a matter of adding the membership provider config to your web.config (and setting the options you want, like number of invalid password attempts, strength requirements, etc.):

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
     type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
     connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
     enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
     enablePasswordReset="true" 
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"  
     requiresUniqueEmail="true" 
     passwordFormat="Hashed" 
     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
     minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
     passwordAttemptWindow="10"      
     passwordStrengthRegularExpression="^.*(?=.{6,})(?=.*\d).*$"  
     applicationName="/" />
```

and adding the [Authorize] attribute to any controllers you want protected. The default ASP.NET MVC project comes with Membership and Forms Authentication already built in. You could copy/paste the Account controller, the Account models, and the web.config section and have a fully built authentication and registration system within a few minutes. This even includes password reset, disabling accounts, profiles, roles and access control (i.e. [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]) means a user must be authenticated, and in the Admin or Super User role.

Answer (score 0):

When you make the new MVC project, choose "Internet Application", it comes with forms authentication prebuilt. If you add an [Authorize] to your Controllers, then you must be logged in to access any part of the app.

That's your best bet to get running as quickly as possible.