# Login screen - should we use cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, session-cookies

I have a login screen, and upon successful login i will display a welcome screen. But the problem is if i refresh the web page. i am taken back to the login screen. If i am successfully logged in, then if i refresh i should go to the Welcome page.

I did some research and found out that i should be using `cookies` to handle this. Is cookies the best approach or are there any other way i could solve this ?

Could someone please point me to a good tutorial that explains how to do this? or some sample code to start with?

Comment: asp.net has built in session management, I would heartily recommend you look into harnessing that.

Comment: are you using asp.net membership api?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the MSDN on the [FormsAuthenticationTicket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx) class that is used for authorizing users to your application.  This is the term that you want to ask about/Google for more information on user authentication.

The basic premise is that once you have authenticated a user, you issue an *encrypted* cookie that contains some basic information about that user.  This cookie is what is used to prove the user is who they say they are, defines the login expiration times and allows you to authorize them to different resources in your application.

**Words of Caution**

With that said, if you are rolling your own authorization/login system, I **highly** encourage you to use the built in .NET membership providers.  There are many caveats to web authorization and authentication and the likelyhood that you leave a security hole open using your own code is extremely high.

Comment: +1. Using cookies is the easiest approach (either custom cookies, or preferably via some existing code like Session state or authentication providers).

Comment: If the username and password is encrypted, what is the server logic to decrypt it ?

Comment: This question is not related to your first question.  You do not store the password in the FormsAuthenticationTicket.  Additionally, by using the built in membership providers, all of the encryption/decryption is done automatically for logging in and for passing the cookie back and forth to the server.  The <machineKey> element is the basis for the .NET authorization crypto mechanism.  I recommend you follow the links from the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524086/user-authentication-and-authorisation-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other approaches that don't require cookies:

- if you can use authentication provided natively by browser (i.e. Windows if your case is intranet with Windows domain) than you can base your decision on headers other than cookie header (i.e. in case of Windows auth you can use "impersonate request as user" functionality) to see if user is "logged in" to your system.
- you can also set information on local system in Local storage to say "this user is logged in" and than check on login page if some other page needs to be rendered. This is not secure approach, but it maybe ok (as you still need to have some way to secure all other pages).